What is the difference between a loop and a Task.WhenAll?
I have a method inside which there is a foreach loop, inside the loop I call several asynchronous operations. I asked ChatGPT to do a review, and he said that you can improve performance by adding tasks to the list and calling Task.WhenAll().
foreach (var name in names)
{
    var some = await SomeMethodAsync1(name);
    await SomeMethodAsync2(name);
    //...
}

Redo to:
var tasks = names.Select(async n =>
{
    var some = await SomeMethodAsync1(n);
    await SomeMethodAsync2(n);
    //...
}).ToList();
await tasks.WhenAll();

And I don't understand why this is more productive? After all, I also call asynchronous methods with await inside Select, then what is the difference from a simple loop?

It depends, do you want to run each loop's logic in parallel or serially?

No answer seems to have mentioned it, yet: Mind the implications on Exception handling! The second example can potentially leave you with "swallowed" exceptions.

I'd also strongly advise against having gibbiddy do reviews. It will happily suggest complete bull (best case) or worse: kind of working but low quality code. Or as in this case: code with not-so-obvious side effects, like swallowed exceptions or potentially high pressure on the thread pool

The ChatGPT answer is useless, as always. If you run things that block each other concurrently, you'll end up with a 10-way block instead of 10x performance improvement. Executing multiple bad queries for example results in each connection blocking the other, resulting in exponential delays. Starting 1000 threads to process 1000 items on a quad-core means a lot of time will be wasted switching between threads. 4 threads processing 250 items each on the other hand, wouldn't have such overhead

A meaningful suggestion for CPU-boudn problems would be to use Parallel.ForEachAsync which would split names into batches and use a separate task to process each batch.

The Parallel.ForEachAsync is generally superior to the Select+Task.WhenAll, for reasons explained in this question, or this.

foreach loop awaits at each iteration. So each iteration starts after previous is done and all calls to SomeMethodAsync1 and SomeMethodAsync2 will be done separately (consecutive) for each iteration.
When you do Select, it starts the task that represent async lambda that you have defined and each item in array is processed in parallel now.
Now having all tasks representing the parallel work, you can use Task.WhenAll() method to await all tasks (btw. it cannot be called as you shown, as far as I know, WhenAll is static method on Task class).
Here's simple example:
Console.WriteLine("NoParallel");
await NoParallel();

Console.WriteLine("Parallel");
await Parallel();

async Task NoParallel()
{
    var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        await AsyncMethod();
    }
}

async Task Parallel()
{
    var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
    await Task.WhenAll(items.Select(x => AsyncMethod()));
}

async Task AsyncMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start async method");
    await Task.Delay(50);
    Console.WriteLine("End async method");
}

Which would print (indicating what is executed in parallel and what not):
NoParallel
Start async method
End async method
Start async method
End async method
Start async method
End async method
Start async method
End async method
Start async method
End async method
Start async method
End async method
Start async method
End async method
Start async method
End async method
Start async method
End async method
Start async method
End async method
Parallel
Start async method
Start async method
Start async method
Start async method
Start async method
Start async method
Start async method
Start async method
Start async method
Start async method
End async method
End async method
End async method
End async method
End async method
End async method
End async method
End async method
End async method
End async method


The first sample runs your processing code on each name one after the other, while the second one starts them all without waiting for other names to complete.
Whether that's an improvement or not depends on what and how you're processing each name.

This should be really obvious based on the name. Task.WhenAll creates a Task that completes WhenAll the Task's in the list complete. It binds a completion action to the Task, so when each tasks completes, it decrements the remaining task count. Once it hits zero, the returned Task will complete. Literally like the name says. Looping over asynchronous functions and awaiting them is executing them in a serial fashion versus executing them concurrently.
Tasks.WhenAll is equivalent to
for(int i = 0; i < alreadyRunningTasks.Count; ++i)
    await alreadyRunningTasks[i];

but with a lot of checks in place, and uses a notification-based mechanism versus multiple waits. source
